# php mysql query strings array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

i am building a string that i check in mysql db.

```
eg:
formFields[] is an array - input1 is: string1
array_push(strings, formFields)
1st string and mysql query looks like this:
"select * from my table where id in (strings)"

formFields[] is an array - input2 is: string1, string2
array_push(strings, formFields)
2nd string and mysql query looks like this:
"select * from my table where id in (strings)"

formFields[] is an array - input3 is: string1, string2,string3
array_push(strings, formFields)
3rd string and mysql query looks like this:
"select * from my table where id in (strings)"
```

i will like to add single quotes and a comma to the array so that i have this for the array strings:
"select * from my table where id in ('string1', 'string2','string3')"

i tried using array implode, but still no luck any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'SELECT ... WHERE id IN ("' . implode('","', $strings) . '")';
```

Comment: Works really well! I want to ask a question, what are the dots exactly doing, are they acting like "+" to glue the quotes with the implode result?

Answer (score 1):

[implode()](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/function.implode.php) is the solution but you shouldn't forget about escaping data:

```
$data = array(...);
array_walk($data, function(&$elem, $key) {
    $elem = mysql_real_escape_string($elem);
});
$sql = 'SELECT ... id IN ("' . implode('", "', $data) . '");';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implode("','",$array);
```

Comment: this doesn't add a quote before and after the very beginning and end of the strings. thanks anyway!

Comment: @Chocho you don't know concatenation too? You desperately need basic PHP classes then.